# Does java.time bring default DateTimeFormatters for patterns such as "yyyy-MM-dd", "HH:mm:ss" or similar variants?

Tags: java, datetime, java-time

I have found myself repeating over and over again the same code pattern. I'm using some sort of date / time object (Java 8 API) and I end up having to roll out my own `DateTimeFormatter`:

```
DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd")
DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss")
```

which is fine but.. it gets me wondering whether there are not already pre-made ones done for me? I took a glance at the ones provided in the `DateTimeFormatter` singleton but they don't seem to be of much help.

Comment: There are so many [Predefined Formatters](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) mentioned in the documentation page. What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: FYI: `DateTimeFormatter` is not a singleton.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss: assemble from built-in parts

As a supplement to the good answer by Meno Hochschild.

> ```
> DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
> ```

While not built in as it stands (even though occurring regularly), my preference is for assembling it from the two predefined formatters mentioned in that other answer rather than writing my  own format pattern string:

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE)
            .appendLiteral(' ')
            .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME)
            .toFormatter();
```

`ISO_LOCAL_TIME` accepts and prints other formats than `HH:mm:ss`, though. On one hand it accepts a format without any seconds (`HH:mm`), on the other hand seconds with a fraction of up to 9 decimals (for example `HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSSS`). It is often an advantage; but if you want to do strict validation of the parsed string or you want string output in a consistent format, it is a drawback, of course.

### Or use String.replace(char, char)

Others would format and parse `LocalDateTime` objects to and from `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` format without any explicit formatter, relying on its resemblance to the ISO 8601 format also mentioned by Meno Hochschild.

```
    String str = "2020-04-17 20:23:30";
    LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse(str.replace(' ', 'T'));
    System.out.println(ldt);
```

Output:

> 2020-04-17T20:23:30

And the other way:

```
    LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Asia/Tehran"));
    String str = now.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.SECONDS)
            .toString()
            .replace('T', ' ');
    System.out.println(str);
```

> 2020-04-18 09:35:38

Comment: The greater flexibility of `ISO_LOCAL_TIME` regarding formats like "HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSSSS" is of course correct. Well, it is up to the OPs needs what is better for him, to use that predefined constant or a strict pattern.

Comment: I have been using the "replace by T" approach until now. I was not aware of the existence of `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` but that's why I created this SO question.

Answer (score 4):

I think the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) of `DateTimeFormatter` is quite clear. The concrete patterns you have mentioned are supported by following predefined constants:

`yyyy-MM-dd` => [ISO_LOCAL_DATE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_LOCAL_DATE)

`HH:mm:ss` => [ISO_LOCAL_TIME](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_LOCAL_TIME)

Only your first example "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" is not matched by any predefined formatter so you can simply construct it by specifying the pattern (as you have already done). `ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME` is very similar but replaces the space by ISO-literal "T".